# SearchField in SAP UI5 does not render suggestions when "X" is clicked

Tags: sapui5

I have implemented a SearchField. When I click on the "X" button, the value gets cleared. Cursor is blinking in the field, but the suggestions do not populate. If I click again in search field still do not populate.
I have to click somewhere else on the page and then again click in the search field again to ensure suggestions populate. How to handle the "X" ?

***View.xml***

```
<SearchField class="" suggestionItems="{path:'model>/names'}" id="names" 
                            value="{model>/header/names}" suggest="onSuggest"  enableSuggestions="true" width="90%">
                            <suggestionItems>
                                <SuggestionItem key="{model>UserId}" text="{order>LastName} , {order>FirstName}"/>
                            </suggestionItems>
                        </SearchField>
```

***Controller.js***

```
onSuggest: function (oEvent) {
        var value = oEvent.getParameter("suggestValue");
        this.oSF = this.getView().byId("name");
        this.oSF.getBinding("suggestionItems") 
        this.oSF.suggest();
```

Comment: Is your model an oData model or asynchronous in any other way?

Comment: @Jorg yes it is oData Model.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried this [attachEventOnce('dataReceived')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51926465/sapui5-search-field-suggestion-autocomplete) solution?

BTW: using

```
this.oSF = oEvent.getSource()
```

instead of

```
this.oSF = this.getView().byId("name");
```

will keep you out of trouble with typos (names <=> name) ;-)