# Suggestion popup doesnt appear for multi input control

Tags: sapui5, autosuggest

I have dynamically attached live search event for my Multi Input control (please refer the below code). Even after attaching the `.bindAggregation` function for `suggestionItems`, the suggestion popup doesn't appear.

```
onAfterRendering: function(oEvent){
     var that = this;
     var oFacetFilters = sap.ui.getCore().byId           
                 ("xyzID").getContent()[0].getContent();

    var oCapTreeFilter =  oFacetFilters[6].getContent()[1];
    oCapTreeFilter.attachLiveChange(function(oEvt){
    //build filter array
    var aFilter = [];
    var sQuery = oEvt.getParameter("value");

    if (sQuery) {
     aFilter.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("RootID", 
          sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, sQuery));
    }

    that.oModel.read("/RootName", {
    async : false,  
    filters : aFilter,
    success : function(oData, response){
        var oJSONModel =  new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            oJSONModel.setData(oData);
            oCapTreeFilter.setModel(oJSONModel);
            oCapTreeFilter.bindAggregation("suggestionItems",{
               path: "/results", 
               template: new sap.ui.core.Item({text: "{RootID}"})
             });
         },
    error : function(response){
         sap.m.MessageBox.show("Error occurred");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is it an oData model? This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51926465/sapui5-search-field-suggestion-autocomplete/51940412#51940412

Comment: Any error message in the browser console? What response you are getting for the backend?

Comment: I dont see any error in console. I'm getting the odata response as expected with filtered data. Just that the suggestion popup doesnt appear.